# Configuring Eclipse with wxPython

Tags: python, eclipse, wxpython

I've been browsing documentation, but haven't been able to find a straightforward tutorial, so I apologize if this is a really simple question.

Anyway, I have eclipse with pydev installed on MAC OSX, and I want configure wxPython to work with eclipse, how do I do this? Once I've downloaded wxpython, what steps do I take to allow wxPython development from eclipse?

***Thanks!***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. I'm on Ubuntu rather than Mac, and I've installed wxPython, so that

```
python -c "import wx"
```

works at a shell prompt. Then, just fire up Eclipse and create a PyDev project, do `import wx` in your code and start using the wxPython API. You should get method completion etc. working as you edit your code, and you can also use the debugger and set breakpoints etc.

Answer (score 7):

Vinay's answer above is correct.  However, if code completion is not picking it up, you might need to add the WX directory to the Pydev's interpreter library path.

> Window | Preferences | Pydev |
>   Interpreter - Python | Libraries

If wx is not present, New Folder and select the install directory.

Comment: You can find the installation dir using `import wx` and `print wx.__file__`

Answer (score 3):

wxPython install by default to the following path /usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0

When adding a path to the Interpreter libraries section in the eclipse preferences add this path: 
/usr/local/lib/wxPython-2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-osx_cocoa